# C++ ambiguous operator for template overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have problem with operator overloading:
I want to write a class with operator like this:

```
class BigNum
{
    public:
        template<class T>
        bool operator==(const T &input);
        template<class T>
        friend bool operator==(const T &A,BigNum & B);
};
```

It's fine to call:

```
BigNum A;
int a;
A==a;
a==A;
```

But when calling:

```
BigNum A,B;
A==B;
```

It will get the compiler error:

> [Error] ambiguous overload for 'operator==' (operand types are 'BigNum' and 'BigNum')
>   [Note] bool BigNum::operator==(const T&) [with T = BigNum]
>   [Note] bool operator==(const T&, BigNum&) [with T = BigNum]

And there is same problem if I change

```
template<class T>
bool operator==(const T &input);
```

to

```
bool operator==(const BigNum &input);
```

But it is OK if the operator overloads are like this(but it can't do`Any type==BigNum`):

```
class BigNum
{
    public:
        bool operator==(const BigNum &input);
        template<class T>
        bool operator==(const T &input);
};
```

If I want to write the operator overload so that it can do all of these:

- Any type == BigNum
- BigNum == Any type
- BigNum == BigNum

How should I fix it?Thank you.

Comment: You need three overloads - a non-template one taking two `BigNum`s, and two templates taking `BigNum` on one side and `T` on the other (those that take `BigNum` on the left could be member functions instead, but personally, I'd make all three non-members, for symmetry).

Comment: When you say "It's fine to call:... But when calling:... error..." your code has an assignment operator `=` not equivalence `==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest removing a member `==` template and just provide three non-member overloads for `operator==` - two templated, one with the `BigNum` on left side, another with it on the right side; and one non-templated with `BigNum` on both sides.

Comment: I got it.Thank you.